# mirroring of nib for arabic language

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, arabic

need mirroring of nib for arabic language support. It can be done by using auto layout leading and trailing property but don't know how to this this in correct way. Please provide sample code or code snippet if anyone have. ﻿

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer: set all the constraints to leading and trailing by default and give support to the arabic language in the app by localising it.

refer the link: https://daw.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/DSAuthWeb.woa/wa/login?path=%2F%2Fvideos%2Fwwdc%2F2012%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D232&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757

Answer (score 0):

You can use localize your nib file.

This may help you :  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/LocalizingInterfaces.html

And one sample tutorial :

http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/09/tutorial-iphone-localization-in-xib-nib-files/

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to localise the nib. Apple gives the support to RTL your nib in ios6 in auto layout. I want that mirroring the nib i don't to make a new nib for this purpose.